# Using chosen.js I lost the elements on the POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in the View:

```
  var writers = new List<Writer> { 
new Writer() { name = "Writer1", surname = "SWriter1" }, 
new Writer() { name = "Writer2", surname = "SWriter2" },
new Writer() { name = "Writer3", surname = "SWriter3" }, 
new Writer() { name = "Writer4", surname = "SWriter14" }, 
new Writer() { name = "Writer5", surname = "SWriter5" }, 
new Writer() { name = "Writer6", surname = "SWriter6" }
 };

  <div>
                @Html.Label("Writers")
                <select class="chosen-select" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select writers of the Film">
                    @for(int i = 0; i < writers.Count; i ++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@writers[i].name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

When I click on the submit button after selecting a couple of writers I lost the elements on the POST. In the controller I am receiving the other elements of the html but no the writers. This is my action method:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "poster, trailer")]Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase poster, HttpPostedFileBase trailer)
```

My model is:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetadata))]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Movie")
public partial class Movie : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
          .....other fields of movie.....

          private EntitySet<Movie_Writer> _Movie_Writers;
    }

class MovieMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]]
    [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Title must have a lenght less than 70")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The realese date of the movie is required")]
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

    public string storyline { get; set; }

    public Binary poster { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Binary trailer { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need to add a List of Writers to my model and modify the action method? Movie_Writer is an intermediate tables because the relation is many to many.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Add `Name` attribute in your `select` tag ,so that you can get data in controller

Update

```
<select Name="YOUR_MODEL_NAME" Class=...>
```